# Chrome does not seem to follow link to css sylesheet. IE and Edge OK

Tags: css, google-chrome

First, please excuse me, I'm a fairly ancient person, and write very simple sites using fairly basic HTML and CSS.  I'm most definitely not a professional and started learning and writing HTML mainly as a way of getting a little mental exercise to delay the onset of senility...   I've used this link

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2018calstyle01.css"
```

IE and Edge work fine but chrome does not display any styles at all, just a plain page of text.  I've tested both locally on my pc and also on a posted webpage - both the same result.

http://www.banado.com/atest/2018cal.htm

The HTML page is essentially a fairly large but simple HTML table, but there is absolutely no style at all on the page, not even any colour.  Any easy way to get round this issue?

[image: This is the link in context]

The Japanese in the html is intentional and displays in all browsers.

Issue now resolved by specifying utf-8 for stylesheet.  Added the following to top of external css stylesheet.

@charset "utf-8";

Comment: Post the link to the webpage.

Comment: Did you used it like this? 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2018calstyle01.css">`

Comment: Post that console output homie

Comment: Cassiano - yes, used it that way.  Cameron - sorry, no idea what you mean...

Comment: It's an encoding issue, the CSS that's served contains chinese characters (yet when you open the file itself in a new tab it is served correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Adam.  Please excuse me - I'm not very knowledgeable about HTML or CSS, but how do you know that this is the case?  Have you looked at the CSS/HTML that I posted on line?  There is some Japanese in my HTML because I put it there.

Comment: Thanks to all, especially Adam.  Issue now resolved by specifying utf-8 for css.